# adding numbers to the list in given intervals python

Tags: arrays, python-3.x

I'm trying to add 'x' into the list 'arr' between the intervals 'a' and 'b'. The list is updated for 'm' times.(i.e)We add 'x' to the list between the intervals 'a' and 'b' for 'm' times.Ive managed to update 'x' value in 'arr' only at 'a' and 'b' and not between the intervals.Kindly help!

```
def main():
arr=[]
n=int(input())
m=int(input())
for i in range(n):
    arr.append(0)
for i in range(m):
    a=int(input())
    b=int(input())
    x=int(input())
    for j,c in range(len(arr)):
            if j==a-1 :
                arr[a-1]=x+arr[a-1]
            if j==b-1:
                arr[b-1]=x+arr[b-1]


    print(arr)
if __name__ == '__main__':
main()
```

Comment: Sorry but the post isn't clear and the code does not reflect the logic you say you are stuck trying to implement. Could you explain what it is you trying to do? What are 'the intervals'? Are a and b having the same result? Why is a, b, x asked for every run of m? It would be super useful if you could give an example input and output

Answer (score 0):

I was unclear on the question, but I think what you are saying you want to do is:

1. Create array
2. Add a number 'x' to indexes of the array
3. Repeat step 2

I have ignored 'm'.

```
  arr = []
  array_length = int(input('Length of initial array >'))
  arr = [0]*array_length # Create the array
  keep_running = True # Replacing the use of 'm' - less parameters for the user!
  while keep_running:

    x = int(input('Number to add >'))
    param_index_start = int(input('Start at index >')) #formerly 'a'
    # Lets check that the start index is valid
    if param_index_start > len(arr):
      print("Start index must be less than initial array length ({})".format(len(arr)))
      continue
    param_index_stop = int(input('Finish at index >')) #formerly 'b'

    arr_length = len(arr)
    # Lets make sure we are not trying to access indexes which do not exist
    stop_index = min(arr_length, param_index_stop)
    start_index = min(arr_length, param_index_start)
    print("Adding {} to indexes {} to {}".format(x, start_index, stop_index))
    # Do the addition
    for index in range(start_index, stop_index):
      arr[index] += x

    print("Current array: ", arr)
    # Allow the user an opportunity to exit
    continue = input("Continue adding? Y/N >")
    if continue == "N":
      keep_running = False
```

Here is some example output (condensed for space)

```
Length of initial array > 10
Number to add > 1
Start at index > 5
Finish at index > 10
Adding 1 to indexes 5 to 10
Current array:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
Continue adding? Y/N > Y

Number to add > 3
Start at index > 4
Finish at index > 7
Adding 3 to indexes 4 to 7
Current array:  [0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1]
Continue adding? Y/N > Y

Number to add > 1
Start at index > 0
Finish at index > 20
Adding 1 to indexes 0 to 10
Current array:  [1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2]
Continue adding? Y/N > N

[1, 1, 1, 1, 4, 5, 5, 2, 2, 2]
```

You can find the repl example [here](https://repl.it/repls/PlaintiveTeemingCurrencies)

I may have misunderstood your question.